# Segmentation Fault after 5th scanf

Tags: c, scanf, segmentation-fault

This code gives a Segmentation Fault at the exact 5th line of input.
   If n<5 or in the debugger everything is fine.

```
scanf("%d %d",&n,&x);
m=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     m[i]=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
 }

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  scanf("%d %d",&m[i][0],&m[i][1]); 

 }`
```

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` in C!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assumes `sizeof (int)` and `sizeof (int*)` are the same

```
m=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Try this

```
m = malloc(n * sizeof *m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake: You allocate memory for `int`s while you need `int pointer`s

(As your `m` array is going to hold pointers for other int arrays)

mistake:

```
m=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

correct:

```
m=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` in C!

Comment: Why? And if it was C++? What's the difference?

Comment: Thank you for that important comment! I've just seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc